# name 'function' is not defined, but it is

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-3.9

What I'm trying to do: I am trying to return a command when it is called after you send a message.

What I sent:
command
hello

Result:
function()
NameError: name 'function' is not defined

How can I fix this?

Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def command():
    global variable 
    variable = False
    async def function():
        variable = True
    if variable == True:
        return

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    function()
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: You're defining it in the local scope, not global. That's not how python works

Comment: How can I define it in the global scope?

Comment: By putting it outside the command

Comment: Alright, but it still doesn't change the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define a function inside another function. Python will not recognize this as an identifier that can be used outside of the scope it was defined in. Move your function definition outside, into the global scope like so:

```
async def function(variable):
    variable = True

@bot.command()
async def command():
    global variable 
    variable = False
    function(variable)
    if variable == True:
        return

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    function(some_other_variable)
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: How can I return the command from the on_message event?